# ProgrammingError (Error during template rendering)

Tags: django, postgresql

> I am getting this Exception in my browser, I have seen upto 20 posts related to this error but I could not have found any solution.I am using Postgre database (pgAdmin 4). I am new to Django, Please help me, Thanks in advance.
>
> I have made a project from djangogirls tutorial http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/#django-girls-tutorial. Then I changed my database to postgre and prject was running as expected. then I made a copy of this project and stored somewhere in my PC. Then I made some changes to my original project with same database settings.
>
> when I run my copy of previous project I found this Error :-
>
> projectname/urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

> My views.py

```
def blog_list(request):
posts = Blog.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
return render(request, 'blog/blog_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

> blog_list.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="date">
            {{ post.published_date }}
        </div>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
        <p>{{ post.short_description|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

> my models.py

```
    class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
    long_description = models.TextField(null = True)
    #text = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class DeletedPost(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

> my appname/urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.blog_list, name='blog_list'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    url(r'^blog/new/$', views.blog_new, name='blog_new'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.blog_edit, name='blog_edit'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.post_delete, name='post_delete'),
]
```

> Error in Browser :

Traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\mysite\blog\templates\blog\blog_list.html, error at line 4
   relation "blog_blog" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."created_date", "blog_blog"."last_updated" FROM "blog_blog...
                                                             ^
   1 : {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 :      {% for post in posts %} 
   5 :         <div class="post">
   6 :             <div class="date">
   7 :                 {{ post.published_date }}
   8 :             </div>
   9 :             <h1><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
   10 :             <p>{{ post.short_description|linebreaksbr }}</p>
   11 :         </div>
   12 :     {% endfor %}
   13 : {% endblock %}

Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "blog_blog" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."created_date", "blog_blog"."last_updated" FROM "blog_blog...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\mysite\blog\views.py" in blog_list
  10.     return render(request, 'blog/blog_list.html', {'posts': posts})

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  238.         self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1085.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  835.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "blog_blog" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."created_date", "blog_blog"."last_updated" FROM "blog_blog...
                                                         ^
```

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` after your latest changes to `models.py`?

Comment: yes, I have checked, it is up to date

Comment: When you check the DB, does it have "blog_blog" table?

Comment: there is no table in postgre :(

Comment: You mean there is no a single table in the database? not even auth table?

Comment: auth table is there but blog table is not there

Comment: what version of django are you using? if >= 1.7 then check that you have "blog" in your inatalled apps in settings.py then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122376/discussion-between-alexxio-and-aman-dhiman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `manage.py makemigrations blog` and `manage.py migrate`. Sometimes `manage.py makemigrations` wont reflect all changes.

The error is telling you that there is no table `blog_blog` in your database from which to pull the data you need. The code you shared looks fine.

Comment: D:\mysite>python manage.py makemigrations blog
No changes detected in app 'blog'

Comment: it is making no changes

Comment: Did you get any errors last time you ran `migrate` and had migrations to commit? Are you able to create blog posts in admin?

Comment: no I did not any errors while running migrate command and I am not able to create any posts right now but some time before i was able to post

Comment: What changes have you made after last time you were able to post? Have you changed databases or `settings.py`?

Comment: I did not change anything to database

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your model is up to date via:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I have checked, it is up to date

Answer (score 1):

Migrate your models to reflect the changes.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

after migrating look at your installed apps in settings.py, you missed a comma after your app name
Installed Applications:
[
blog,
]
It's because of that comma it cannot detect your app name.